# Is possible dequeue/remove style from wp_footer() hook and add on wp_head() hook?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions, footer, wp-head

I need unregister this enqueue style of wp_footer() hook and add it to the top of site with hook wp_head(), this is possible?

I'm optimizing my theme to validate in W3C, and one of the requirements of W3C is that all styles are within the tag `<head></head>`... I am using an specific plugin called `Crayon Syntax Highlighter`, and this plugin are inserting a style at the bottom of the page (probably using `wp_footer()` hook).

The name/id of script is `crayon`:
[image]

I've tryed all this functions but no success:

```
wp_deregister_style( 'crayon' );
wp_dequeue_style( 'crayon' );
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_style' , 'crayon' , 10 );

wp_deregister_style( 'crayon-css' );
wp_dequeue_style( 'crayon-css' );
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_style' , 'crayon-css' , 10 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/crayon-syntax-highlighter/trunk/crayon_wp.class.php), you can see that `wp_enqueue_style( 'crayon' )` is called in `Crayon::enqueue_resources()` which itself is called either from either `Crayon::the_content()` or `Crayon::wp_head()`. The code in `Crayon::wp_head` is:

```
if (!CrayonGlobalSettings::val(CrayonSettings::EFFICIENT_ENQUEUE) || CrayonGlobalSettings::val(CrayonSettings::TAG_EDITOR_FRONT)) {
  CrayonLog::debug('head: force enqueue');
  // Efficient enqueuing disabled, always load despite enqueuing or not in the_post
  self::enqueue_resources();
}
```

Which will enqueue the style only when certain settings are enabled. Otherwise, the style will only be enqueued from `the_content` filter which fires after `wp_head` has already been output.

So your two options are:

1. Have the CSS enqueued on all pages in the header
2. Have the CSS enqueued only on necessary pages but in the footer

Comment: Option 1! Thanks! On options panel, have a miscellaneous options called: ´Try loading CSS Crayon and JavaScript only when needed´, so I disable this and style back to head, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm.. the question is not very clear to me, if you could provide a little more info about your issue (like the specific files and scripts you need to modify) would be great. From what i understood, i'll try to help you. First, avoid plugins unless you really really need them. Now, you might be trying to move render-blocking JavaScript and CSS out of the  tag, that's because when you start loading a page through your browser, the first scripts you download are those between the  tag, by moving those scripts to your footer (footer.php or /public_html/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/footer.php) the Web page will start rendering all the data that needs to be visualized first, beginning from the top of the page and at last those scripts in the footer.php file. I bet
`Crayon Syntax Highlighter` is causing the issue, just try to put this `<!-- W3TC-include-js-head -->` before the closing `</body>` tag.

If you want to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` look at this example

```
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'core', 'style.css', false ); 
}

function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```

I hope this helps, good luck dude. :)

Comment: The solution is what the Nathan Johnson says... Thanks anyway for help!